# Genexus: access sub grid's data when clicking its control

Tags: genexus

I have two SDT collections with the following structures:

```
Areas           (collection)
L Area          (structure)
  L Codigo      (char 20)
    Orden       (num 2.0)
    Rojo        (num 3.0)
    Verde       (num 3.0)
    Azul        (num 3.0)
    Mostrar     (char 10)
    Camas       (SDT Camas)
```

```
Camas           (collection)
L Cama          (structure)
  L Id          (num 8.0)
    Paciente    (num 8.0)
    Edad        (char 10)
    Nombre      (char 30)
    Comienzo    (datetime)
    Duracion    (char 10)
    Evento      (num 8.0)
    Area        (char 20)
    Cama        (char 20)
    Sector      (char 20)
```

Then, I have a Web Panel with one Free Style Grid based on `Areas` SDT collection through an `&areas` variable. Inside that Grid I have a normal Grid based on the `Camas` SDT collection through `&areas.item(0).Camas`.

This works well enough. The panel has a block for each area thanks to the Free Style Grid, and inside each block I have a list of each area's 'camas' (beds) through the normal Grids.

Now I need to make the `Nombre` control for each sub grid clickable and make so the data in `Paciente` is saved to the WebSession of the user. I thought I could use `&areas.CurrentItem.Camas.CurrentItem.Paciente` but that doesn't work.

What would I need to do to access a sub grid's data when clicking its control?

I'm using Genexus 16 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get the behavior I wanted.

Instead of basing the subgrid on the `&areas.item(0).Camas` collection, I removed the reference to the collection and used a `&cama` variable based on the `Camas.Cama` substructure for all items inside the grid. I also added a `&paciente` variable to the grid. Then, I just loaded each `&cama` while looping inside the `&areas.CurrentItem.Camas` collection, and gave &paciente the same value as '&cama.Paciente'.

After that, I can access the data I wanted through the `&paciente` variable when executing the click event of any control inside the sub grid.

Code:

```
Event GridAreaCamas.Load
    For &cama in &areas.CurrentItem.Camas
        &paciente = &cama.Paciente
        GridAreaCamas.Load()
    EndFor
EndEvent

Event ctlPacienteNombreCompleto.Click
    &webSession.Set(!"paciente_seleccionado", &paciente.ToString())
EndEvent
```